# Accepted answer reputation disappears?

Tags: bug, reputation, accepted-answer

Twice today I noticed that my reputation increases with 15 on Stack Overflow, but when I click to see my account, the change is being reverted and none of my recent answers are marked as accepted. Then why does the reputation on the top of the page change ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OP of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16718728) first accepted your answer, then accepted another answer instead, unaccepting yours. See the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16718728/timeline):

> ```
> 16:21  accepted   A   StinePike
> 16:21  unaccepted A   kocko
> 16:21  accepted   A   kocko
> ```

I see this more often from newer users; most often they tried to award the 'accepted answer' to two or more answers on the page, only to discover you can only pick one.

An accept, unaccept pair on the same day is removed from your reputation graph to reduce clutter, so you won't see that in your graph. I had to go through your recent answers one by one to find this one.

The rep counter in the top bar, as driven by the websocket, doesn't update when you loose an question accept, you'd need to reload the page to see it reflect the proper reputation when that happens.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't know this feature of StackOverflow. :)

Comment: @kocko: It's rather hidden; you need to know the URL exists, or use a [user script that adds a `timeline` link to questions](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a). I believe the devs were planning to improve it and 'hid' it from the public UI until they could get to that task. It's been like this for a while now.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably someone accepted your answer and un-did that right away. Reputation gain increases the rep in the top bar but reputation loss will not be updated automatically.

Comment: If someone un-accepts an answer, there is a result in the `Reputation history` and in the current (two) cases, there isn't such.

Comment: It won't be listed in the reputation history if the accept mark will be reverted fast.

Comment: Oh, I see. Looked weird, because this happened twice today. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe the user was very unsure and changed his mind several times.

Comment: @juergend: Not just very fast. Anytime during the same day it was accepted, in fact.